# $(C^1[0,1], || . ||_\infty)$ is not Banach Space.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

Recently, I am studying Banach Space.
I know that $(C[0,1], || . ||_\infty)$ is a Banach Space and closed subspace of Banach Space is Banach. This follows from the result that closed subset of complete space is complete. I have shown that $(C^1[0,1], || . ||_\infty)$ is not a closed subspace of $(C[0,1], || . ||_\infty).$ This can be shown using "Stone Weierstrass" theorem. Up to this is fine. Now my problem is from here can I say that $(C^1[0,1], || . ||_\infty)$ is not Banach? Or I have to give a counter-example so that $(C^1[0,1], || . ||_\infty)$ is not complete. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a sequence of $\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$ function that converges uniformly to $|x|$ ?

Comment: The limit function is not differentiable. So, the sequence in $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$ is not uniformly convergent to $|x|.$ Am I right?

Comment: No you are not !

Comment: What is my fault? Please help.

Comment: As I said : Take a $\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$ sequences that converges uniformly to $|x|$.

Comment: $f_n(x)=\frac{n|x|} {1+n}.$ Where $x\in [0,1].$

Comment: Yes, this work.

Answer (score 0):

What about the sequence $(x_n)\subset  C^1[0,1]$ given by $x_n=x^n$?

Comment: this is even not uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Surb It is continuous on a compact interval thus uniformly continuous.

Comment: @AnthonyTer: Please, read the question.

Comment: This is not a Cauchy sequence in $C^1$ with $\sup$ norm, I believe.